# JIRA Customization And difference between label and component

Tags: jira

I want to create a project in the JIRA.
The project should be able to select the type of work and choose another project.

I wish user can create selected another project because there are many large numbers of projects. 
and type of work can choose two or three depth.

First.
type of work use customfield.
choose another project use component.
-Team member should be an administrator permission in project.

Second 
type of work use customfield.
choose another project use label.

Is there a better plan?

Last I want to know difference between label and component and version.
I think user can create label and project admin can create label, component, and version. The label applies entirely. But component and version applies project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JIRA: Epics vs Labels vs Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076263/jira-epics-vs-labels-vs-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be trying to do something which I don't think is possible: an issue is in exactly one project at a time.

Components are a lot like labels, but are selectable from a set defined for a project. It can sometimes be useful to define components which align across multiple projects. You're correct that creating components requires admin privileges, while anyone can create labels; this can make for an excess of different labels if they aren't used with some care and discipline, but the components list will stay as clean as the admins keep it. An issue can relate to multiple components and have multiple labels. Sharing labels or components across projects may achieve what you're after.

Because components are a "privileged" class of labels, it's often wise to spend a bit of time considering a sensible scheme for them based on the anticipated breakdown of issues; changing them in bulk midway through a project can be tedious.

I'm less familar with versions; I'm not sure whether an issue can be linked to multiple versions. They are usually used to group issues for release planning, but that isn't imposed by the tool, they could be used for something else; it might be confusing for users making assumptions about what "Version" means, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer your question, as there are some grey areas, but will try to briefly explain the difference between labels, components and version.

**Project and components**

First of all, a project is (a project) a collection of issues (stories, tasks, bugs, etc.), so components are just sub-sections of a project. They could be either defined based on the architecture of your product. Also, a component can be assigned by default to a particular user or group. An example of components could be database, UI, notifications.

**Labels**

Labels help you categorise and search for an issue and have the advantage of allowing multiple labels to an issue.

**Versions**

A version is a set of stories and bug-fixes and helps you plan the release of those stories and fixes to the customer.

The main way to categorise the type of work within a project is to add different types of issues and for each one define custom fields, screens, and workflows.